# CASE WHEN creates duplicate rows with results to all conditions (Yes AND No)

Tags: sql, case

When the 'Yes' condition evaluates true, the results have duplicate rows - one row with the 'Yes' result and one with the 'No' result. I'm not sure why it is evaluating to both 'Yes' and 'No.'

As you can see in the image, when the 'No' condition evaluates as true, no duplicate is resulted. Has anyone ever had this issue?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PAT.PAT_ID,
    PAT.PAT_NAME AS [PATIENT]   
    ,CONVERT(DATE,HSP.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,101) AS [ADMISSION DATE]
    ,CONVERT(DATE,HSP.INP_ADM_DATE,101) AS [INPATIENT ADM DATE]
    ,CONVERT(DATE,HSP.HOSP_DISCH_TIME,101) AS [DISCHARGE DATE]
    ,ZPC.NAME AS [PATIENT CLASS]
    ,FAD.INP_LENGTH_OF_STAY AS [INP LENGTH OF STAY]
    ,CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,101) IS NOT NULL AND 
     FAD.INP_LENGTH_OF_STAY IS NOT NULL  THEN(
         CASE WHEN 
             ((COUNT(
                CASE WHEN 
                ((SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                 AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) >= '07:00' AND 
                 (SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                 AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) <= '19:00') 
                THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PAT.PAT_ID, 
                CONVERT(DATE,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,101))
               ) >=2 
              AND
             (COUNT(
               CASE WHEN 
                ((SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) < '07:00' OR 
                (SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) > '19:00') 
               THEN 1 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY PAT.PAT_ID, 
                CONVERT(DATE,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,101))
              ) >=2 )
        THEN 'YES' 
        WHEN ((COUNT(
                CASE WHEN 
                ((SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) >= '07:00' AND 
                (SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) <= '19:00') 
                THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PAT.PAT_ID, 
                CONVERT(DATE,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,101))
             ) < 2 
             OR 
             (COUNT( 
                CASE WHEN 
                ((SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) < '07:00' OR 
                (SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(TIME,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,108) 
                AS VARCHAR(10)),1,5)) > '19:00') 
                THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PAT.PAT_ID, 
               CONVERT(DATE,HNO.CRT_INST_LOCAL_DTTM,101))) < 2 ) 
       THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END) 
   END AS [TWO POC NOTES PER SHIFT?]

FROM    PAT_ENC_HSP HSP
        LEFT JOIN ZC_PAT_CLASS ZPC ON HSP.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C = 
        ZPC.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C 
        INNER JOIN PAT_ENC PEN ON HSP.INPATIENT_DATA_ID = 
        PEN.INPATIENT_DATA_ID
        LEFT JOIN HNO_INFO HNO ON HSP.INPATIENT_DATA_ID = 
        HNO.INPATIENT_DATA_ID 
        INNER JOIN PATIENT PAT ON HSP.PAT_ID = PAT.PAT_ID
        INNER JOIN VALID_PATIENT VP ON PAT.PAT_ID = VP.PAT_ID
        LEFT JOIN F_IP_HSP_ADMISSION FAD ON HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = 
        FAD.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

WHERE   VP.IS_VALID_PAT_YN = 'Y'
        AND PEN.ENC_TYPE_C IN ('3') 
        AND HSP.ADMIT_CONF_STAT_C NOT IN ('3') AND HNO.IP_NOTE_TYPE_C = 
        '1000001'
        AND HSP.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C = '101'
ORDER BY PAT.PAT_NAME
```

[Results returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soyhT.jpg)

Comment: Make it easy to help you - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have not read your entire post, but it is well known a single case will never return two results. You obviously have joined your tables in a way other than you think, which for every row you expected produces multiple rows, and these have different data on which case is dependent and thus yields different resuts.

Comment: Thank you both. Sorry, I'm new to the site and have seen others post details so I included my entire query. I'll reduce it and repost. Thanks George, that is very helpful- I'll check my joins.